# Want to use my own console over eclipse, but encounter some unkown error for package not found

Tags: java, eclipse

```
package ex;

public class Ex1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Hello...!!");
        System.out.println("just to view the screen ");
        String name = myconsole.getString("Enter UR Name");
        myconsole.print(name);
    }
}
```

Here I can't find the pacages to be add to make the console run as a script

```java
import java.util.*;//The imports can finds the package here??
import package  ex;

public final class myconsole {

        private static Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);
        static void print(String msg) {
            System.out.println(msg);
            
        }
        
        static String getString(String msg)
        {
            print(msg);
            return sn.nextLine();
            
        }
        static int getNumber(String msg) {
            return Interger.parseInt(getString(msg));
            
        }
        static double getDouble(String msg) {
            return Double.parseDouble(getString(msg));
            
        }
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
```

There is error with the package not found.

Comment: `import package  ex;`? That's a compile error.

Comment: is thtat so let me try that

Answer (score 1):

`package` must be the first thing in the Java file. So the lines:

```
import java.util.*;//The imports can finds the package here??
import package  ex;
```

are wrong in your `myconsole` class. Eclipse should be showing you an error.

Probably you want:

```
package ex;

import java.util.*;
```

Also note that the Java convention is that class names start with an upper case letter and are 'camel case'. So `MyConsole` rather than `myconsole`.

Comment: yes its woking that paticular error is fix now thank you sir